# Color coding imported docx document

Tags: r, officer

I'm trying to highlight a set of words, for example `word1` and `word2` from an imported word document using the officer package in R. I am now stuck after setting the text properties for the word. How do I get officer to highlight the words in the colors?

I've read the data file using `read_docx(filename)`.
I've also set the text properties using `fp_text()` and `ftext()`.

```
my_doc <- read_docx(file.path(filepath,myfile)) 

color1 <- fp_text(color = "blue", font.size = 10, bold = FALSE,
        italic = FALSE, underlined = FALSE, font.family = "Arial",
        vertical.align = "baseline", shading.color = "transparent")
ftext("word1", color1)
color2 <- fp_text(color = "red", font.size = 10, bold = FALSE,
        italic = FALSE, underlined = FALSE, font.family = "Arial",
        vertical.align = "baseline", shading.color = "transparent")
ftext("word2", color1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the highlight color with argument `shading.color`:

```
color1 <- fp_text(shading.color = "yellow")
```

Comment: Thanks!! Also, how would I replace my word document which I loaded in using officer with the highlighted and color texts?